# Python convert nested json form response to a dataframe (multiples levels)

Tags: python, json, dataframe, rest, nested

I'm trying to convert Nested Json response to a dataframe but basic way using pd.json_normalize(response.json())  generates more than 2000 columns...

Here is my nested json's structure:

```
"form_items":{
"1218738":{"name":"Autocapture","field_type":"autocapture","options":{"type":"datetime","datetime":"modified_app_utc"},"page_num":"1","page_name":"Section 1","pos":"1"},
"1218739":{"name":"Agent name","field_type":"checkbox","page_num":"1","page_name":"Section 1","pos":"2","items":[{"name":"Agent 1"},{"name":"Agent 2"},{"name":"Agent 3"}]},
"1218740":{"name":"Type","field_type":"radio","page_num":"1","page_name":"Section 1","pos":"3","items":[{"name":"Monthly","opts":"conditional":["1218746"],"default":["1"]}},{"name":"Annual","opts":{"conditional":["1218747"]}}]},
"1218746":{"name":"Works fine ?","field_type":"radio","page_num":"1","page_name":"Section 1","pos":"9","items":[{"name":"Yes"},{"name":"No","opts":{"conditional":["1218747","1218750"]}}]},
"1218747":{"name":"Comment","field_type":"input","options":{"type":"textarea"},"page_num":"1","page_name":"Section 1","pos":"10"},


"data":[
{"event_name":"Event num 1234",
"last_modified":"2023-07-19 13:01:12",
"Event_status":"to be validated",
"Event_id":91458,
"Member_id":50348,
"Member_label":"the guy next door",
"1218739":{"value":"test1","modified":"2023-07-19 13:01:12"},
"1218740":{"value":"Monthly","modified":"2023-07-19 13:01:12"},
"1218741":{"value":"Bad","modified":"2023-07-19 13:01:12"},
"1218743":{"value":"Normal","modified":"2023-07-19 13:01:12"},
"1218746":{"value":"Yes","modified":"2023-07-19 13:01:12"},
"1218751":{"value":"Normal","modified":"2023-07-19 13:01:12"},
"1218747":{"value":"amazing comment","modified":"2023-07-19 13:01:12"},
"subpages":[]
},
{"event_name":"Event num 1235",
"last_modified":"2023-07-18 08:40:27",
"Event_status":"finished",
"Event_id":87692,
"Member_id":90348,
"Member_label":"2d guy next door",
"1218739":{"value":"test16","modified":"2023-07-18 08:40:27"},
"1218740":{"value":"Annual","modified":"2023-07-18 08:40:27"},
"1218741":{"value":"Good","modified":"2023-07-18 08:40:27"},
"1218776":{"value":"Normal","modified":"2023-07-18 08:40:27"},
"subpages":[]},
],
"has_more_pages":true,
"pages":10,
"can_contain_repeatable_section":"0"
```

with 2 main keys "form_items" and "data".

- "form_items" contains the description of the form with form_items_id's like "1218739" which has :{"name":"Agent name"} and some items possible.
- "data" contains details and form_items_id with value. it can have like 30 form_item_id with value.

The tricky part in "data" is that the form_item_id ("1218738") is not isolated and I'm did not success to extract this part...

Basically I just want to put on a dataframe Data sections with :

- a form_items_id columun with the id "12xxxxx"
- column with the name of the form_items_id
- column with the value

Any idea ?